# Finding first repeated consecutive entries in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of two columns **Stock** and **DueDate**, where I need to select first row from the repeated consecutive entries based on stock column.

**df:**

[image: df]

I am expecting output like below,

**Expected output:**

[image: output]

> **My Approach**

The approach I tried to use is to first list out what all rows repeating based on **stock** column by creating a new column **repeated_yes** and then subset the first row only if any rows are repeating more than twice.

I have used the below line of code to create new column "repeated_yes",

```
    ss = df.Stock.ne(df.Stock.shift())
    df['repeated_yes'] = ss.groupby(ss.cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
```

so the new updated dataframe looks like this,

**df_new**

[image]

But I am stuck on subsetting only row number **3** and **8** inorder to attain the result. If there are any other effective approach it would be helpful.

> Edited:
> Forgot to include the actual full question,
> If there are any other rows below the last row in the dataframe **df** it should not display any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain another mask created by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` by `&` for bitwise `AND` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
ss = df.Stock.ne(df.Stock.shift())
ss1 = ss.cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)

df = df[ss & ss1]
```

Comment: Yeah. Got it. Have included the full question which I forgot to include in the bwginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224031/discussion-between-joe-and-jezrael).